# Is there a Vue.js form validation library that shows errors on blur, hides errors immediately when fixed

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm searching for a Vue form validation library to use in a Nuxt app, that will let me show errors under a field on blur (so users don't for example see an invalid email error as soon as they type the first letter of their email address), but that will hide errors immediately when fixed (before blur) to give users immediate feedback when fixing errors.

So far I've looked at Vuelidate and Vee Validate and as best I can tell, neither support this. I'm looking through the validation libraries listed at https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#validation and also want to try https://github.com/blocka/vue-simpleform which is based on Formik that I've enjoyed using with React, however it would be super helpful to know if anyone else has accomplished what I want with any Vue validation library.

The trouble seems to be that Vue validation libraries either use `v-model=` data binding in which case errors appear before blur (see https://jsfiddle.net/buj06y1a/) or `v-model.lazy=` in which case errors don't appear until after blur which I like, but also don't disappear until after blur (see https://jsfiddle.net/toequ523/) which I don't like.

Comment: https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/1426

Comment: I tried VeeValidate because it looked easy to use but had a terrible experience with it, I couldn't get basic functionality like custom error messages or password confirmations working. However it's interesting to see they are aware of this issue.

Comment: That really strange because all.og this things work, and vee validate have best support ever :)

Comment: Maybe I should try opening some VeeValidate issues, I was discouraged by immediately running into multiple problems...kind of defeats the purpose of using a library.

Comment: Well I solved my VeeValidate problems by reading the documentation :) I think I made the mistake of trying to follow some incorrect/outdated posts elsewhere.